# WebClient.DownloadStringAsync With Response in http?

Tags: windows-phone-7

Currently i am doing this way

> string url = ("http://localhost/json.aspx");

```
        WebClient xmlClient = new WebClient();
        xmlClient.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(XMLFileLoaded);



        xmlClient.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(url));
```

However how do i add values that should be send together with the downloadstring?
For example in android, i am able to use namevalue pair

```
        httppost.setEntity( new UrlEncodedFormEntity(    nameValuePairs, "UTF-8"));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would **strongly** recommend that you use [RestSharp](http://restsharp.org/) for this, rather than attempting to hand-code it.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need `HttpWebRequest` to POST data. The post data must be generated manually: Converting the key-value pairs to the right format.

Check out these classes: 
http://mytoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Http

(GZIP support, POST data, POST files, ...)